# intel_pstate driver drives me crazy

Tags: drivers, intel

i've got some problems with the intel_pstate driver.

Problem 1) I can't disable Turbo. It's disabled in the BIOS & via:

```
root@think:~# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo 
1
```

Problem 2) I can't limit the maximum frequency. "max_perf_pct" is set to 33, "min_perf_pct" the same. The CPU totally ignores all settings:

```
Socket [0] - [physical cores=2, logical cores=4, max online cores ever=2]
TURBO DISABLED on 2 Cores, Hyper Threading ON
Max Frequency without considering Turbo 2893.00 MHz (99.76 x [29])
Max TURBO Multiplier (if Enabled) with 1/2/3/4 Cores is  36x/34x/34x/34x
Real Current Frequency 3227.37 MHz [99.76 x 32.35] (Max of below)
      Core [core-id]  :Actual Freq (Mult.)      C0%   Halt(C1)%  C3 %   C6 %
    Core 1 [0]:       3227.37 (32.35x)      44.4    39.2       0       1
    Core 2 [2]:       3189.89 (31.98x)      43.3    44.3       1       1
```

"TURBO DISABLED on 2 Cores"... i don't think so?

```
analyzing CPU 0:
driver: intel_pstate
CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.60 GHz
available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.60 GHz.
              The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
              within this range.
current CPU frequency is 1.20 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
```

Thanks

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: root@think:~$ uname -a
Linux think 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux